# How do I handle too many permutations?

Tags: performance, artificial-intelligence, permutation

My question is: How can I calculate chances of winning when there are too many permutations for a complete go trough.

I'm developing a Poker Texas Hold'Em App. The basic function is a probability calculator. A Deck consists of 52 cards, each player holds two cards, 5 cards are placed on the table and then the winner gets evaluated. So if there are 4 cards on the table, there are 44 possible outcomes for the last card. When there are 3 cards on the table, there are 45*44 permutations. But if there are no cards ont the table, I have to consider 48*47*46*45*44 = 205.476.480 permutations. If I manage to implement the "order doesn't matter"-part perfectly I would have 1.712.304 permutations, which is still about 15 times too much for my CakePHP Webserver.

Comment: Rather than trying to make CakePHP handle this, why not run another more efficient service locally or remotely to handle these requests?

Answer (score 0):

The key is to consider only the relevant cards.
Instead of creating and evaluating every possible combination of hands, only consider those combinations that actually improve your hand.

An example (not complete)

The hand is 5 of heart + 8 of spades. The following card combinations improve this hand:

- Any card above 8
- One, two or three 5s
- one, two or three 8s
- combinations of the above
- any value appearing two or three or four times
- 5 crosses or 5 diamonds
- 4 hearts or 4 spades
- 6, 7, 9
- 4, 6, 7
- similar combinations of 4 or 5 cards
- 6, 7, 8, 9 of hearts
- similar combinations with hearts and spades

For each of those, you can calculate the probability fast.

Early in around, you can speed up the computation by ignoring combinations that require more than n matching cards, because they have almost no effect (everybody has a chance of a royal flush in the beginning, but most never get one).

You can even precalculate the values for the starting hands. These are just approx 13 * 13 values (13 options for each card, times 2 for suited or not, divide by two because the order is irrelevant).

Comment: Thank you very much. So I only consider cards that improve both players hands and then I do the run through routine that I already implemented and all cards that do no improvement are all the same to the routine. I need to think about it for a while.